# strange cscope command line limitation

Tags: c, development-environment, cscope

Cscope has eleven search input fields in interactive mode. But when I try to use it in line-oriented output mode and specify `Find all symbol assignments:` field using `-10` switch it does not work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment option was added by RedHat patch, it is not part of the original cscope. Seems like they patched only ncurses interface  without updating the corresponding command line options.

Answer (score 1):

I also see some little strange-ness.

In terminal,

```
cscope -d
```

gives the following options

```
Find this C symbol:
Find this global definition:
Find functions called by this function:
Find functions calling this function:
Find this text string:
Change this text string:
Find this egrep pattern:
Find this file:
Find files #including this file:
```

But, using my cscope plugin in gvim,

```
:cs help
```

gives the following options

```
find : Query for a pattern            (Usage: find c|d|e|f|g|i|s|t name)
   c: Find functions calling this function
   d: Find functions called by this function
   e: Find this egrep pattern
   f: Find this file
   g: Find this definition
   i: Find files #including this file
   s: Find this C symbol
   t: Find assignments to
```

The "Find assignments to" option is available only in the second.

So, for line-oriented output mode, the closest seems to be the "Find this text string:" option. That can be done as

```
cscope -d -L -4 <text>
```